# QRegexp Missing Digits

Tags: regex, qt

We are all stumped on this one:

```
QRegExp kcc_stationing("(-)?(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)[^a-zA-Z]");
QString str;
if (kcc_stationing.indexIn(description) > -1)
{

    str = kcc_stationing.cap(1) + kcc_stationing.cap(2) + "." + kcc_stationing.cap(3);
            qDebug() << kcc_stationing.cap(1);
            qDebug() << kcc_stationing.cap(2);
            qDebug() << kcc_stationing.cap(3);
            qDebug() << "Description: " << description;
            qDebug() << "Returned Stationing string: " << str;
}
```

Running this code on "1082.006":

[image]

Note the missing "6"

After some just blind guessing, we removed `[^a-zA-Z]` and got the correct answer. We added this originally so that we would reject any number with other characters directly attached without spaces.

For example: 10.05D should be rejected.

Can anyone explain why this extra piece was causing us to lose that last "6"?

Comment: Is the final '6' not being matched by the `[^a-zA-Z]` item -- and hence not appearing in the capture?  Try `[^a-zA-Z]*` instead to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick! I really didn't expect the [^a-zA-Z] to matter at all. I thought the 6 should be picked up by the \\d+ proceeds it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^a-zA-Z]` is a character class. Character classes match one character. It will not match the end of a string, since there is no character there.

To get that result, the engine will match all the numbers with the `\\d+`, including the last one. It will then need to backtrack in order for the last character class to be satisfied.

I think you want to allow zero-width match (specifically when it's the end of the string). In your case, it would be easiest to use:

```
(-)?(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)([^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

Or, if Qt supports non-capturing groups:

```
(-)?(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)(?:[^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

Note that I also recommend using `[.]` instead of `\\.`, since I feel it improves readability.

Comment: Interesting--but that still doesn't tell me why the 6 isn't getting picked up by the (\\d+) before it.....

Comment: @Mizmor I've elaborated a bit on backtracking. Does that help to explain it better?

Comment: Ah--Yes it does now. That also explains why GM's original suggestion did the trick.